# Separate design for child and parent menu in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css

I have designed menu in asp.net with css. when i set the parent menu design, it reflect in child too. i have planed seperate design for child,.

1) How can i stop the reflection in Child design as in parent.
2) How can I design the Child menus.

MY DESIGN (WHAT I WANT) -
[image]

I gave my code below

**CSS-**

```
 div.menu
        {
            height: 40px;
            width: 560px;
            background: #FDF378;          
            -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
            -moz-border-radius: 15px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            font-size:25px;   
            text-align:center;    
        }

        div.menu ul li
        {
            border-right-color:Blue;
            border-right-width:2px;
            border-right-style:groove;            
        }

         div.menu ul li:last-child {  
            border: none;
        }

        div.menu ul li:hover
        {
            border-top-style:solid;
            border-top-width:5px;
            border-top-color:Red;
        }
```

**XAML -**

```
 <asp:Menu ID="mainMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" CssClass="menu" autopostback="true">
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu1" NavigateUrl="#">
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu1" NavigateUrl="#" />
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu2" NavigateUrl="#" />
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu3" NavigateUrl="#" />
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu4" NavigateUrl="#" />
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu5" NavigateUrl="#" />
                </asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu2" NavigateUrl="#" >
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu1" NavigateUrl="#" />
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu2" NavigateUrl="#" />

                </asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu3" NavigateUrl="#" />
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu4" NavigateUrl="#" />
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu5" NavigateUrl="#" />
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>
```

**OutPut (WHAT I GOT) -**

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why you added the XAML tag to the question.

Comment: Is xaml wrong tag?. I am not think that.

Comment: The XAML I'm thinking of is eXtensible Application Markup Language is the primary markup language for WPF, Silverlight and  Windows Apps.   I don't see any that XAML in your code examples.

Comment: ok, now i have removed the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the CSS code to build the second level drop down menu.

first you have to build a submenu then you have to hide it and on hover you can make them visible.  Here is the Working [Demo](http://jsbin.com/yogicadu/1/).

```
/*NEw lines Added to make a Submenu */

div.menu ul li ul
{padding:0 margin:0 -webkit-border-radius: 15px; border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;background: gold; width:150px; display:none; position:absolute; right:0; }

div.menu ul li ul li{border-bottom:1px solid black;border-right-style:none;  }

div.menu ul li ul li:hover{ border:0 none;}
div.menu ul li:hover >ul {display:block;}
```

Here is a dummy HTML code.

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>Menu 1</li>
      <li>Menu 2</li>
      <li>Menu 3</li>
      <li>Menu 4</li>
      <li>Menu 5 
      <ul>
         <li>Sub Menu 5.1</li>
         <li>Sub Menu 5.2</li>
         <li>Sub Menu 5.3</li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>   
  </div>
```